# What is needed to run Roslyn on Teamcity?

Tags: teamcity, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, c#-6.0

With Visual Studio 2015 having been released yesterday my dev team is very interested in upgrading and using the new C# 6.0 features and as we all have MSDN it is something that would definitely be possible.

However I am worried that our Teamcity builds will fail without performing some work to upgrade the build agents.

So has anyone gone through this process yet, or know what would be needed?

**Edit:** I did some research into Teamcity and noticed that on the [What's New](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/whatsnew/) page for version 9.0 and 9.1 that it adds support for VS 2015, so does that cover what would be needed? And also since we are running TeamCity 8.0 would there be any way to add Roslyn support without upgrading?

Comment: We are planning to run a test with a non prod instance of teamcity so I may be able to post an answer myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can install either the [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159), or else install the [Microsoft.Net.Compilers](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/), NuGet package in your project to use Roslyn compilers.

Comment: Great thanks for the information, do you know if I would be correct in assuming the latest version of TeamCity would not need anything extra?

Comment: I don't know. I've never used TeamCity.

Answer (score 3):

This is an addition to @Kevin answer.

- Install [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159)
- Go to {TeamCity Folder}\{Build Agent Folder}\conf
- Edit buildAgent.properties  Add The following Lines

  MSBuildTools14.0_x64_Path =C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin\\amd64 MSBuildTools14.0_x86_Path
  =C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin
- Save it
- you should see the changes on the Agent Configuration Parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you've already installed [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) and you are still getting the build errors about C# 6.0, try to install a newer .NET version on your TeamCity's machine, like .[NET 4.6.1](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=49981)

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything listed here and still kept getting compiler errors.  I had to follow steps taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095531/is-it-possible-to-configure-teamcity-to-use-the-msbuild-that-ships-with-visual-s#36336980) to finally get things compiling with Roslyn:

```
Rename C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0 => C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0-old
Copy C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0 => C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0
```